# How to force stream RTP video with vlc over tcp protocol?

Tags: tcp, streaming, vlc, rtp

I'm trying to stream a video via rtp with vlc, the default protocol is UDP, but its performance is very low (bitrate, resolution, smooth,..)

So, I want to use vlc with rtp to stream video over tcp protocol to gain higher performance.

Are there anyone can help me to force vlc streaming rtp over tcp protocol.
Please help me if you have any idea.

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is an extremely broad question;(

Comment: Why is it broad? He event gives a reason on why he wants to try forcing VLC to use RTP over TCP. Sounds quite specific to me

Comment: If you are using the app, in "Open Network Stream" click on "show more options" and add `:rtsp-tcp` to "Edit Options" so it would look like " :network-caching=1000 :rtsp-tcp"

Comment: These instructions are helpful: http://rg4.net/archives/1104.html `Tools –> Preferences –> Input & Codecs - Find “Network” settings, and check RTP over RTSP (TCP) option, then restart/reopen your rtsp network stream` I think this may be client-side only though?

Answer (score 11):

If you're using the command-line client then add the --rtsp-tcp options:

`vlc --rtsp-tcp rtsp://path/to/stream`

Comment: This option only works when you use VLC as an rtsp client. Unfortunately, VLC streaming server does not support rtsp over tcp.

Answer (score 2):

This article may be useful:
https://web.archive.org/web/20151117041313/http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?64-How-to-configure-VLC-media-player-for-RTSP-RTP-playback-(RTSP-RTP-interleaved-and-tuning)

> This article explains how to configure the VideoLAN VLC media player to stream live or on demand streams through RTSP/RTP over TCP (RTSP/RTP interleaved). While HTTP streaming is a newer standard offering more features, RTSP/RTP streaming may work better when streaming through a firewall/router, which doesn't have UDP streaming open.

Comment: the article url has become stale, updated it to fetch from archive.org